# Is GPU debugger (beta) from Android Studio 2.2 working?

Tags: android-studio, debugging, opengl-es, android-studio-2.2, exoplayer

I am trying to debug some OpenGL code, so I wanted to make use of the GPU debugger from Android Studio. For this I need to get a GPU trace, according to the steps detailed at [https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-gpu-debugger-trace.html](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-gpu-debugger.html). But, after the dialog for trace name, Android Studio shows directly the message: Failed to attach to process.

Android Studio has version 2.3, and was recently updated.
On the device (Samsung S3) I see the alert: !Waiting for debugger.. process zzz is waiting for debugger to attach.

I tried to enable all GPU related options from developer options in device settings, also to disable all, with the same result. Is this feature working? My setup is not very uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

I reached to a point where I get the message: The GPU debugger does not currently support tracing on this device. So the answer would be that it does not work on S3. I'll leave the question here, maybe it will save someone a few hours of investigation.

When trying to enable Run/Debug Configurations>Profiling>Capture GPU Commands, I was required to install "GPU Tools". Then, after accepting to install, it complained that they were already installed in the folder, and I should remove them prior to new installation. So I moved them away. Then it would give the error from the question.

After some attempts, I decided to put the contents of the folder back, deselect/select again Capture GPU. It said once again that I needed to install GPU tools, but this time I did nothing. The checkbox got checked anyway, and when trying to start the trace, went on to do some stuff without complaining about the attaching to the process. Finally it did not work anyway, but at least I know the reason.

Comment: I did not have any success with the built-in android studio GPU tracer either. It required root for my phone. The debugger from the "Android Device Monitor" on the other hand worked just fine and it has similar features.